# Ruby equivalent of this curl command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, rest-client

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @filename.json
```

I am looking at [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem and cant figure out how to do this. I need this for making a bulk request to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rest-client`

```
RestClient.post 'localhost:9200/_bulk', File.new("filename.json", 'rb'), 'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

not sure if `rest-client` automatically set `content-type`, just check without it.

Comment: Thanks, actually this worked for me:

`RestClient.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', File.new("filename.json")`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the standard library (without any additional gems):

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:9200/_bulk')
data = File.read('filename.json')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

response, body = http.post(url.path, data, {'Content-type'=>'text/xml; charset=utf-8'})
```

Comment: yes, but I already have `RestClient` gem inside my project. So, this is what worked for me: `RestClient.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', File.new("filename.json")`